# Add Sum of all values from locators of a web table, method results values of only first two locators

Tags: javascript, protractor

I want to add all the values of locators  from a web table but it is adding only first two values. here is my method declaration below.

```
exports.GetMonthsFWSeasonSTDPreMkdValues = () => {
  var total_value;
  for(var month_index = 9; month_index <= 18 ; month_index++){
    const elm_xpath = utils.GetXpathForSubCategory(chosen_season_index, month_index);
    return browser.element(by.xpath(elm_xpath)).getText().then(function(response_total_months_index_values){
      total_value += response_total_months_index_values;
      console.log('total value' ,total_value);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: You should initialize `totalValues` to `0`.

Comment: i have tried that too.still the same result.

Comment: There are too many unknowns here for someone to track this down.  Can you create a **[minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** that doesn't depend on your `utils`, `browser`, or `by` objects?  (In trying to do so, you may well find the issue yourself!)

Answer (score 1):

The root case is you use `return` inside `For` loop, thus the loop only be iterated one time.

And another hiddened code issue is javascript closure issue, the `For` loop execute as Sync, but the `getText()` inside loop execute as Async.

If you remove keyword `return`,  the `browser.element(by.xpath(elm_xpath)).getText()` will repeat use the `elm_xpath` of month_index=18

```
exports.GetMonthsFWSeasonSTDPreMkdValues = () => {
  var promises = [];

  for(var month_index = 9; month_index <= 18 ; month_index++){
    const elm_xpath = utils.GetXpathForSubCategory(chosen_season_index, month_index);
    promises.push(element(by.xpath(elm_xpath)).getText());
  }

  return Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){

    return data.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){
        return accumulator + currentValue * 1;
    }, 0);

  });

};
//Remind: this function return a promise.
```